# Why is the beer head and head retention important?

Tags: head, head-retention

Does the head improve something on the beer flavour/aroma?

Back home in Brasil, the folk has it that head is useful to keep the beer cold, but in colder lands (and warmer beers) as they have in Europe that is probably a non-issue.

In fact, some fast drinkers over there would argue for smaller head to get more beer.

Why head and head retention are important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Head is primarially aesthetic, you can gather some useful information about your brew process.

- You could possibly be under pitching or fermenting too warm leading to an increase in fusel alcohols, which have been shown to destroy the compound used to create foam.
- If you are cleansing with household agents, the residue from them may reduce your head, its best to use brewing specific cleansers.
- If your beer isn't otherwise carbed up make sure you are using the proper ratio of priming sugar.

I say that if the beer tastes okay in the end you're doing okay, but a good head and carbonation has been shown to lead to a better mouthfeel for beer.

http://www.brewersfriend.com/2009/12/19/beer-head-retention/
http://beersmith.com/blog/2008/06/25/enhancing-beer-head-retention-for-home-brewers/

Answer (score 2):

Beer head is mostly an aesthetic issue. Some argue that it also serves to trap aromatics, but this effect is debatable. For the most part, though, if you're not concerned with it there's no reason that you should be.